# looped batch file, naming subfolders with a title,date, and time

Tags: windows, date, batch-file, optimization, time

(TLDR see last paragraph)

Below code I have cobbled together with information from other threads in this forum and others. I am very new to this code/language so I don't have  a clue how to optimize this.

Here is what I am trying to achieve with this code.

script outputs to a .log instead of command window
:top
script searches for a .dat file in "M:\AnalysisDrop\"
if a .dat file is detected (
script automatically creates a subfolder "M:\AnalysisDrop\title_date_time"
file is moved into the folder
file is opened with the program C:\Analysis\Analysis.exe
)
wait 5 seconds
goto top  (repeat forever)

this script will continuously repeat for what I hope to be a very long time.  Will I run into issues with too many "set" commands? I ran into some issue with doing "SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion" and SETLOCAL DisableDelayedExpansion

```
@Echo off
echo Script 1 Initiated
@echo on
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%I in ('wmic os get localdatetime /format:list') do set datetime=%%I
set datetime1=%datetime:~0,8%_%datetime:~8,6%
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
SET LOGFILE=Script1_LOG_%datetime1%.log
call :top >> %LOGFILE% 
exit /b 0
:top
for %%f in (*.dat) do (
set datetime1=%datetime:~0,8%_%datetime:~8,6%
set foldername=%%~nf_%datetime1%
md "!foldername!"
move "M:\AnalysisDrop\%%~nf*.dat*" "M:\AnalysisDrop\%%~nf_%datetime1%\"
pushd M:\AnalysisDrop\%%~nf_%datetime1%\
C:\Analysis\Analysis.exe '%%~nf.dat'
popd
)
timeout /t 5 /nobreak
goto top
exit /b 0
```

I honestly dont need the "for" loop but i'm not sure how to do otherwise (tried to replace "for" with "if", no success. Also, the "datetime1" variable wont update, so if I try to run multiple .dat files of the same name, it writes over the previous one in the same subfolder, which I can live with but prefer not to have.

So to clarify my questions:
1. How do i do this without the "for" loop? I understand this may be causing my issue of the datetime variable not updating.
2. I used the "goto" command to continuously loop this script, should I use something different?

Comment: Your code only creates `%datetime%` once at the beginning, how do you expect it to update when your loop never returns to that portion of the code?

Comment: as @Compo said, you only set datetime once and that variable will remain. Secondly you should consider looking at ENDLOCAL when swopping between delayedexpansion enabled and disabled. Finally, why do you need to run a for loop getting wmic datetime variables , when you can use the default cmd variables already set as %date% and %time% ?

Answer (score 0):

Answer to my question, with help from @compo. I wasn't aware that I needed the `for \f...` statement in the loop as well as the `set datetime2`. I needed to change `%datetime...%` to `!datetime...!` throughout the for loop. See below for fixed code.

In response to @Gerhard Barnard, `%time%` and `%date%` is not in a format that I can name directories with unfortunately.

```
@Echo off
echo Script 2 Initiated
@echo on
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%I in ('wmic os get localdatetime /format:list') do set datetime=%%I
set datetime2=%datetime:~0,8%_%datetime:~8,6%
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion 
SET LOGFILE=Script2_LOG_%datetime2%.log
call :top >> %LOGFILE% 
:top

for %%f in (*.dat) do (

for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%I in ('wmic os get localdatetime /format:list') do set datetime=%%I
set datetime2=!datetime:~0,8!_!datetime:~8,6!
set foldername=%%~nf_!datetime2!
md "!foldername!"
move "M:\AnalysisDrop\%%~nf*.dat*" "M:\AnalysisDrop\!foldername!\"
pushd M:\AnalysisDrop\!foldername!\
C:\Analysis\Analysis.exe '%%~nf.dat'
popd

)

timeout /t 5 /nobreak
goto top
exit /b 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this, *based upon your original code*, helps you with structuring your script:

```bat
@Echo Off
Rem Enabling delayed expansion
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
Rem Setting current directory
If /I Not "%CD%"=="M:\AnalysisDrop" (CD /D "M:\AnalysisDrop" 2>Nul||Exit/B)
Rem Setting date and time variable for log file name
Call :GetLDT
Rem Call Main section outputting to log file
Call :Main>>"Script1_LOG_%LDT%.log"
Rem Exit script
Exit/B

Rem Main section
:Main
Rem Loop over each matching file in the current directory
For %%A In (*.dat) Do (
    Rem Setting date and time variable for destination directory name
    Call :GetLDT
    Rem Create directory if it does not exist
    If Not Exist "%%~nA_!LDT!\" MD "%%~nA_!LDT!"
    Rem Move file to directory
    Move "%%~A" "%%~nA_!LDT!"
    Rem Run analysis against file in destination
    Start "" /D "%%~nA_!LDT!" /W "C:\Analysis\Analysis.exe" '%%~A'
)
Rem Create a delay 
Timeout 5 /NoBreak>Nul
Rem Re-run Main section in loop 
GoTo Main

Rem GetLDT section
:GetLDT
Rem Setting date and time string
For /F "EOL=L" %%A In ('WMIC OS GET LocalDateTime') Do For %%B In (%%~nA
) Do Set "LDT=%%B"
Rem Formatting string as required
Set "LDT=%LDT:~,8%_%LDT:~-6%"
Rem Return to point after Call
GoTo :EOF
```

Your command using `'%%~A'` looks wrong with single quotes, but I'll leave that to you to decide.